# How to see memory usage in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, debugging, memory-management, monitoring, usage-statistics

How to see memory usage in a Laravel app? This is for testing and to approximate how much server memory (RAM) resource I need to setup for my server usage assumptions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To see a Laravel app's memory usage, install [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

This is the easiest way to track a Laravel app's memory usage and many other things like database queries, requests, durations, exceptions etc. Saves you time from reading lots of configs, codes and other workarounds found online.

Here, a fresh [Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) app uses 3.73MB of memory:
[image]

*(may vary or fluctuate around 3.75MB)*

Comment: Add anything and that will significantly rise. Laravel / PHP is great, although compared to node / express its memory hungry.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan Comparing Laravel to Express doesn't really make sense because the latter includes a friction of what Laravel includes out of the box. You can compare Symfony to Express if you want to see somewhat more relevant results.

Comment: @andonovn Very true. Also I dont think memory should really be a reason one considers which language / framework to choose. That would be working backwards.

Comment: Using this technique to check the memory for Laravel 8.x and 9.x shows 5MB on first load, and 1MB for subsequent loads (in PHP 8.1).