# Find how much RAM a Laravel app instance is using?

Tags: php, laravel, memory, cpu, laravel-9

I need to figure out how much RAM/CPU a particular Laravel app is using, but so far the current code shows the *entire system's* usage.

How can I, instead, check how much RAM/CPU only *one* Laravel app is using? *(kind of how the Windows task manager shows each program's CPU/RAM usage- but for web apps instead [particularly Laravel, but vanilla PHP solutions are welcome])*

Current code below...

web.php:

```
...
Route::get('/details', function () {
    //RAM usage
    $free = shell_exec('free'); 
    $free = (string) trim($free);
    $free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
    $mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
    $mem = array_filter($mem);
    $mem = array_merge($mem);
    $usedmem = $mem[2];
    $usedmemInGB = number_format($usedmem / 1048576, 2) . ' GB';
    $memory1 = $mem[2] / $mem[1] * 100;
    $memory = round($memory1) . '%';
    $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo', 'r');
    $mem = 0;
    while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
        $pieces = array();
        if (preg_match('/^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)\skB$/', $line, $pieces)) {
            $mem = $pieces[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
    $totalram = number_format($mem / 1048576, 2) . ' GB';
    
    //cpu usage
    $cpu_load = sys_getloadavg(); 
    $load = $cpu_load[0] . '% / 100%';
    
    return view('details',compact('memory','totalram','usedmemInGB','load'));
});
...
```

details.blade.php:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <h2 class="no-margin text-semibold">Current RAM Usage</h2>
    <div class="progress progress-micro mb-10">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-indigo-400" style="width: {{$memory}}">
        <span class="sr-only">{{$memory}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right">{{$usedmemInGB}} / {{$totalram}} ({{$memory}})</span>  

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <h2 class="no-margin text-semibold">Current CPU Usage</h2>
    <div class="progress progress-micro mb-10">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-indigo-400" style="width: {{$load}}">
        <span class="sr-only">{{$load}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right">{{$load}}</span>   
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is your answer I think https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar probably duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684716/19168006

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Laravel to detect how much resources is Laravel consuming from your server resources, instead I would use server monitoring tools.

```
htop
```

Is a very good command that we can use to detect what apps are using our server the most and how much!

Now if you are good with servers, I advise you to use https://prometheus.io/, Use it with https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/ to detect the RAM usage etc...

There is a good documentation but if you faced any troubles, please comment and I'll help you with the server installation for both apps!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), where you can see how much memory the application consumes.
But, it's a little deceptive because the debugbar itself takes from memory, so it's more for informational purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could get the memory usage of you web server thread, not exactly what you need but very close.

Suppose you use linux system (tested on my CentOS7+XAMPP environment):

```
$pid = getmypid();
exec("ps -eo%mem,rss,pid | grep $pid", $output);
$output = explode("  ", $output[0]);
dd($output[1]); // result in kB
```

For windows (tested on my Win10+XAMPP environment):

```
$output = array();
exec( 'tasklist /FI "PID eq ' . getmypid() . '" /FO LIST', $output );
dd($output[5]); // result in kB
```